# Wrap Raw Speex in OGG Container

Tags: ogg, speex

are there any libraries that allow one to pack raw speex into an ogg container? 
I know Jspeex, but - as far as I can see - this library only handles Ogg/Speex and PCM. 
But I already have a Speex stream and want to wrap this in an Ogg container.

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java, there is [Ogg for Java](http://netmind.hu/ogg/).

For C, you can use [libogg](http://xiph.org/ogg/) or [liboggz](http://www.xiph.org/oggz/). Here is an example which uses liboggz to encapsulate an audio stream encoded by libfishsound:

- https://github.com/kfish/libfishsound/blob/master/src/examples/fishsound-encode.c

Comment: Thanks Conrad, Ogg for Java was the one I was looking for

Comment: I wanted to use the Ogg for Java Library for wrapping Speex in OGG, but I wasn't successful.
I also tried to use the sources of jspeex. My problem here is, that I need some information of the speex-encoded data to build a OGG container (e.g. sampling rate, isVBR, mono/stereo, frameSize, ...). Is there a possibility to get these information from the raw speex stream?